# Is the Melon-Pult worth its price?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

I just got the Melon-pult which costs 300 sun. However since pults fire at a 1/2 rate, it has the same effect as a reapeater ( reapeater has 40  dps while melon pult has 80 dps but fires half as fast ) but with splash damage. A reapeater costs 200 sun so is the extra 100 sun used for splash really worth it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Melon-Pults are the best if you use them right, especially in endless levels.
They are best used on the lines just below the top one or just above the bottom one due to their Area Of Effect.

The DPS you get from a single plant is much better then any other plant you can get due to the Enemy clumping up in large waves. Let's say you got a tall-nut with 5 zombies chewing on it. All 5 get hit at the same time by a Melon but the repeater only hits one.

And to top the Melons off, if you upgrade them with frost bonus you can effectively slow all incoming enemies with just 2 plants total. So, Yes! The splash is worth it, and the slow bonus you get with upgrading it makes it even better!

Comment: Whats the frost bonus? I've remembered from wiki ( on another device ) It is an upgrade plant called Winter melon.

Comment: Zombies move and attack at half speed, so your plants on the frontline like Tallnuts will survive longer and your spiky grass would have more time to damage enemies.

Answer (score 1):

For big crowds, yes.
For smaller crowds where the splash is ineffective, it's still a good idea.
80 DPS is big against normal zombies and others, even against bucketheads!
If you know there are lots of enemies in a level, I advise using Melon pult.

Comment: I atcually havent played PvZ 2. Too pay to win for me!

Comment: Hello,Eris the guest , I have a new question about plants vs zombies and I was hoping that you would know the answer...its about last stand. I will upvote your answer if you happen to know, thanks!