# Is the Winter Melon worth its price?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

Due to having a [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/378135/is-the-melon-pult-worth-its-price) about melon pult that has a comment mentioning that the melon pult has a frosty upgrade, I soon figured out the upgrade it the winter melon. The winter melon costs 500 sun and is a melon pult that can slow. However, it seems a little weird that the winter melon costs 200 more sun just for the slow. It does not have any advantages over the melon pult other than being able to slow zombies, hence the snow pea (being only 175 sun) seems like a much better alternative for it. Is the winter melon worth it?

Answer (score 2):

Winter Melon is much more powerful then the Snow Pea.
Why?

- Area of effect, The snow Pea only hits the front zombie, so if 5
  zombies are chewing on your tall nut 1 of them get's 50% attack speed
  reduction the other 4 can chew on ahead. in levels with larger waves
  the Melon Pult is one of the most powerful plants in game.  And this
  is even without taking in consideration that it slows the row above
  and below as well.
- It also does 80 damage per hit to ALL zombies in a 3 by 3 area while
  the snow pea only hits a single target for 20.

Seeing it's the best Damage per second plant (tied with the un-upgraded version) and not considering the explosive plants...and that it slows all zombies in a 3 by 3 area it is worth to have especially in the endless map where you will have more sun then room for plants.